# Session exception error

Tags: c#, .net, session

My code is giving me this error i am not getting why and to do 
"Error 13 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'"
I am already using sessions to get a parameter at another page and method and works fine, now i want to use the same paramenter in a Schedualed Job i created for my app but is no working.

```
public static bool UpdateActivationResult(string recordId, string resultPart, string failureMessage, int reconciliation_count)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        OracleTransaction transaction = null;
        OracleCommand cmd;

        string updateQuery = "";
        int rowsUpdated = 0;
        string notes = "";
        string branch = clsUtility.GetHO;
        clsUtility.CDFOperations operation = clsUtility.CDFOperations.CanNotActivateCard;
        string userLoggedBranch = "";

        try
        {

            userLoggedBranch = Session["userDegaS"].ToString(); //this row is giving me error

            clsUtility.WriteLog4Net(recordId + " - " + resultPart + " - " + failureMessage, null, clsUtility.LogType.Debug, "");

            using (conn = new OracleConnection(clsUtility.ConnectionString))
            {  etc
```

i want to use this parameter in calling this method

```
if (reconciliation_count == 5 && !resultPart.Equals("SUCCESS"))
                    {
                        Utility.clsUtility.SendNotificationAsHTML(recordId, branch, operation, userLoggedBranch);                          
                    }
```

Any idea where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Session` property is a non-static property that is defined on the base `Controller` in .NET ([msnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session(v=vs.118).aspx)).

The the code listed with your question, you are trying to access this non-static method from without a static method. That is not possible.

You can solve it three ways:

1. If the method is within your controller, you can simply make it non-static in order to access the `Session` property.
2. You can also pass along the property you need (`userLoggedBranch`) as a parameter into your method `UpdateActivationResult`. Whatever action is calling that method will simply have to pass this value.

   So something along the lines of:

   ```
   public static bool UpdateActivationResult(
           string recordId, 
           string resultPart, 
           string failureMessage,
           int reconciliation_count,
           string userLoggedBranch) {  
       // Your method code
   ```
3. Pass along the session itself, or something from which you can access the session (such as `HttpContext`, or the `HttpRequest`).

---

Comment: can you help me how can i archive your second aproach? Tried making the method non static but there were other things not working as they should]

Comment: I updated the answer with an addition of the method. However, it's just adding another parameter to the method. Does this help at all?

Comment: I understand now, but i can not think of any other way of getting this value other than the session. Is not that is saved somewhere in the DB or smth like that

Comment: @Lara As you are trying to access a session value I'll assume that the outcome depends on the user that initiated it. Meaning that there must be somewhere where an event is processed that _eventually_ calls this method. Most likely you are able to access the session there, you'll need to pass it down along with the other value in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare userLoggedBranch as static variable or better is to simply access session in the respective method instead of passing it as a parameter

Comment: Talwar you mean like this  public static string  userLoggedBranch = ""; ??? Cuz is not working

Comment: Is your method static?

Comment: Yes it is. now i am getting this errors also "Invalid expression term 'public' " and "Invalid token '"userDegaS"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration "

Comment: Declaring user related information as a static variable is a very bad idea. If _UserA_ would set this value, it would be set for all users. Especially if further processing is done based off this value it could cause undesired results.

Comment: You can simply access session in the respective method instead of passing it as a parameter